# How to submit the information from a drop-down list to the Spring Controller?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to pass the information about what project I selected from a list of projects. For that I made an HTML page that contains a form.

```
<form th:action="@{/cidashboard/table}" th:object="${projectVariantSelected}" method="post">

<p>Project variants options:</p>
    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{projectVariantId}">
        <option  th:each = "projectVariant : ${projectsVariants}"
                 th:value="${projectVariant.projectVariantId}"
                 th:text="${projectVariant.projectVariantName}">
        </option>
    </select>

<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is my POST request:

```
@PostMapping("cidashboard/table")
 public String createTable(@ModelAttribute("projectVariantSelected") ProjectVariant projectVariantSelected) {

 System.out.println("Project Variant selected: " + projectVariantSelected.getProjectVariantName() + projectVariantSelected.getProjectVariantId());

 return "test1";
}
```

I received this error:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'projectVariantSelected' available as request attribute
```

Comment: The error which you're having is because you are not  sending your `projectVariantSelected` object from controller where you're sending your `projectsVariants` list to thymeleaf cz you're using `@ModelAttribute` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id from th:object must represent an existing object from the model. You can do something like this in your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void addAttributes(Map<String,Object> model) {
    model.put("projectVariantSelected", new ProjectVariant());
}
```

Your model attribute must be initialized before returning the view. Spring tags will take your thymeleaf view fields and will populate the available model attribute.